# my report viewer rdlc report is not displaying the data.c# sql 08

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

my report viewer rdlc report is not displaying the data. The report is completely blank. I checked the query i have written in data set table adapter and it is correct. I tried everything whatever i could but data is not loading. I just cant figure out whats te problem.
the same code is working for my another report for which i have attached diff table.the code is :

namespace BillingMaster
{
    public partial class ReportAllForm3 : Form
    {
        public ReportAllForm3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void ReportAllForm3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ReportAllDataset3.BillingDetails' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
       // this.BillingDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.ReportAllDataset3.BillingDetails);

  this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.BillingDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.ReportAllDataset3.BillingDetails, dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(), dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

}

and i have taken date column as date datatype only.
I am writing query below:

SELECT SrNo, Package, Type, DiscPer, DiscAmt, TotalAmt, noofttkts, BillNo, TaxAmt, Rate, BillNoTop, PackageTop, DiscperTop, DiscAmtTop, TaxPerc, Tax, Date FROM dbo.BillingDetails where Date  between @date1 and  @date2 order by Billno

can anyone tell me what shall I do ?